# How to handle Soft Keyboard in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, keyboard, uinavigationbar

I am working on a chat application. And in my app, I don't want to hide my top navbar when the keyboard appears or when the keyboard presented to the screen. I am using the following code to achieve my goal.

```
 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var  newYpos = CGFloat()
    let rate = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        self.customView.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
        newYpos = keyboardSize.height
        //   print(newYpos)
        self.tap.isEnabled = true
    }
    if self.yPosAfterFirstNotif == 0.0{
        self.yPosAfterFirstNotif = newYpos
        UIView.animate(withDuration: rate.doubleValue, animations: {
            self.customView.bottomC.constant = (-self.yPosAfterFirstNotif)
        })
    }
    self.customView.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, newYpos, 0)
    //scrollToBottom()
    self.customView.tableView.scrollToBottomm()
    self.customView.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

And this is how I hide my keyboard

```
  @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
          var  newYpos = CGFloat()
      let rate = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
            {
                 newYpos = keyboardSize.height
                 self.yPosAfterFirstNotif = newYpos
                self.customView.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, newYpos, 0)
            }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: rate.doubleValue, animations: {
                self.customView.bottomC.constant = (+self.yPosAfterFirstNotif)
            })
            //  self.constraintCommentViewBottom.constant = 0
            self.yPosAfterFirstNotif = 0.0
            self.customView.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, newYpos, 0)

        self.tap.isEnabled = false


        if self.customView.ChatTextField.text.characters.count == 0
        {
            self.customView.sendButton.isHidden = true
            self.customView.recordButton.isHidden = false
            self.customView.cameraButton.isHidden = false
            self.customView.textFieldTrailling.constant = 44
        }




    }
```

> before presenting keyboard

[image]

> after presenting keyboard

[image]

> after dismissing keyboard

[image]
Need Help
Thanks

Comment: Are you using custom navigation bar or default ? if you are using custom then which view is superview of navbar ? I mean if you have added navbar to self.view and given constraint of tableview's top from navbar frame then it will not create problem.

Comment: yes i am using custom tabbar. and i have bounded top anchor or tableview to the bottom of navbar

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: @BhavsangJam i think i have already share my code. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add below code to hide/show navigation-bar on hide/show of keyboard

Also you can manage scroll in same method based on keyboard size.

**Updated Answer ::**
You can set constraints to bottom of view contains textfield and update it on keyboard show\hide. It works for me.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
     guard let userInfo = (sender as Notification).userInfo, let value = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
    let newHeight: CGFloat
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        newHeight = value.cgRectValue.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    } else {
        newHeight = value.cgRectValue.height
    }
    self.chatViewBottomConstraints.constant = newHeight
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.scrollToBottom()
    }

}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.chatViewBottomConstraints.constant  = 0.0
        self.tableView.scrollToBottom()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, my navbar moves upward not entirely but a bit. and when i dismiss keyboard it remains to its new state

Comment: @hussnainahmad Can you please share the code of keyboardWillHide ?

Comment: Ok can you share the screenshot of the issue? As currently you updated the question my answer won't work.

Comment: please have a look on it now. please view navigation bar before and after presenting keyboard and after dismissing keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think your `keyboardSize` in `keyboardWillHide` is not correctly, try to use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfokey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`